# .Htaccess redirect to 404 page when certain files doesn't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've been working with my own MVC system for a while now and it works great!

I use this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, when a page (controller) doesn't exist, I redirect to /error *(in the index.php file)*.
But there are some scenarios when a picture will be deleted in a folder, and still be printed in the html page. This will automatically make the browsers call the picture, which doesn't exist (So it will call the /error page)

Now what I want to do is that, when a picture, or any file, (except, php,html files i guess) I would like to redirect to a 404 file instead of the /error.

I am certain that this could be solved in the .htaccess file, but me and Apache aren't so buddies at the moment. Anyone who is friend with Apache?

Thanks!

Comment: i found this:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder|otherfolder)/

Comment: So problem solved now?

Comment: nope didnt work, not sure why

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess code here? Esp the rule that redirects to `/error`

Comment: i dont redirect to /error in htaccess, i do it in index.php when it cant find the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your images are in a common subfolder, for example `/images` in `http://example.com/images/img.png`, you can alter your rule to exclude this subdirectory completely, then add an errordocument. This .htaccess should be in your www-root.

```
RewriteEngine On

#If the file does not exist, and the url doesn't start with /images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

#If the rule above didn't match, and the file does not exist, use the ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

See

- [Documentation for ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)
- [Documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [Free friendship coupon for Apache](http://ode.apache.org/img/asf.png) (might or might not be expired)

Comment: not working might be becuause i got my image folder like this:
example.com/name/mysite/images/...

does the path have to be absolute? or is it enough with /images

Comment: it worked now when i used an absolute path, but is it possible in some way to use it in a realtive path that's not absolute.. ? like the system knowing that the .htaccess file is inside example.com/name/mysite/ , so i wont be forced to type the full path , and only images/

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` is always relative to the www-root. You could remove the `^`, giving it the meaning "if there is 'images' somewhere in the path" rather than "if there is 'images' at the beginning of the path". The first argument of RewriteRule removes the directory .htaccess is in from the url, so it would only match against 'images'. I think it was something `(?!images)` that would create a negative lookahead. I find that it becomes confusing though, and prefer a condition over such a lookahead.

Comment: thanks that solved it, to bad that its not possible to do load an errorDocument by a relative path