# How to display error page instead of showing file in my directory on my cpanel server

Tags: php, linux, server, cpanel

Can anyone help with how to display the error page instead of showing the directory for my files when no file is pointed to on the URL? For instance, in the attached picture I simply remove thefile.php and input the URL on a browser like [www.mywebsite.com/foldername/](http://www.mywebsite.com/foldername/) instead of [www.mywebsite.com/foldername/thefile.php](http://www.mywebsite.com/foldername/thefile.php) and it displays all the files under this folder. I want it to redirect the user to the error page instead of showing all files in this folder.[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to to it would be to create an index.php file inside that folder with the content bellow:

```
<?php

$dir   = "."; // the directory you want to check
$exclude = array(".", "..", "index.php"); // ignore . .. and file itself
$files = scandir($dir);
$files = array_diff($files, $exclude); // delete the entries in exclude array from your files array

if(!empty($files)) {
   echo "there are files";
}
else
{
    header("Location: /404.php");
}

?>
```

When you access http://url/folder, index.php is the default php file loaded, so if there is nothing else in the folder except for the index.php file, it will show the 404 page (you have to replace the /404.php page with whatever page you have for handling 404 errors)

I assume you could do it with some regex in .htaccess as well

Comment: My bad, I forgot the {} after if

Comment: i still got "This page isn’t is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Ok, it should work now, I've corected the code (I've edited it from my phone initially)... I just tested on my linux server and it works just fine

Comment: Is there a way to add 404.php to all folders on the server without having to place index.php in all the folders?

Comment: No ideea, but you could check this, it might be helpfull -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097624/htaccess-redirect-to-404-page-when-certain-files-doesnt-exist